# Symfony routing yml file with optional parameters

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, routes, yaml

I am trying to route a URL in symfony, the URL to be matched has 3 variants

```
/test/param1/test.json
/test/param1/param2/test.json
/test/param1/param2/param3/test.json
```

I want to do this with a single controller and param2 and param3 are optional parameters.

I have tried regex in **requirements** param2 and param3 to allow a string and nothing, but I can't get all 3 paths to match to go to the same controller.

Comment: The simpler way I see is to declare 3 routes pointing to the same action

Answer (score 1):

You could use only one route parameter that allow the "/", and then split the parameters in the controller. Something like this :

```
_test:
    path:     /test/{params}/test.json
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Demo:test }
    requirements:
        params: .+
```

And the controller :

```
public function testAction(Request $request, $params)
{
    dump($params); // param1/param2/param3
    $paramsArray = split("/", $params);
}
```

This would work for any number of parameters!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define different routes and assign them to one Controller-Action:

```
testparam123:
   pattern:   /test/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/test.json
   defaults:  { _controller: Bundle:Controller:test}
testparam12:
       pattern:   /test/{param1}/{param2}/test.json
       defaults:  { _controller: Bundle:Controller:test}
testparam1:
       pattern:   /test/{param1}/test.json
       defaults:  { _controller: Bundle:Controller:test}
```

Then you contoller action method looks something like

```
public function testAction($param1,$param2=NULL,$param3=NULL) {
   // do something
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with one route config. If params should be optional, then you must left query param empty like

```
/test/param1/param2//test.json
```

Here symfony knows that param3 is empty. Otherwise you never know which part of the url is empty because you could make this:

/test/param1/param3/test.json

How should symfony recognize that param2 is missing and param3 instead is given?
You could change the logic from

```
/test/param1/param2/param3/test.json
```

to

```
/test/param1-param2-param3-test.json
```

Thats much easier to handle.

Comment: I think CiTNOH's solution would not match this:

Comment: /test/param1/param3/test.json